# How to add local storage to updated/edited text?

Tags: javascript

I have managed to successfully add local storage to the addToDo function. So when a todo item is added the local storage is set and retrieved for each item(line 33 in codepen). However, I cannot figure out how to add the same local storage function to the updated item text. *Note: To update item, user clicks off of item after typing in textarea.*

If I add the addToLocalStorage function in the createTodoText function before itemText is returned, it does not work. If possible I also need to add local storage for the checkbox state and delete state as I am sure it is similar. [This codepen](https://codepen.io/swgj19/pen/bGWLEYe) is what I have tried.

```
const createTodoText = (todo) => {
    const itemText = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
    itemText.setAttribute('id', 'display-text');
    itemText.classList.add('todoText');
    itemText.addEventListener('input', function () {
        updateHeight(this);
    });
    itemText.value = todo.name;
    //update todo item when user clicks away
    itemText.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
        todo.name = e.currentTarget.value;
    });
    //addToLocalStorage(todos)
    return itemText;
};

const addToLocalStorage = (todos) => {
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
  renderTodos(todos);
}

const getFromLocalStorage = () => {
  const reference = localStorage.getItem('todos');
  if (reference) {
    todos = JSON.parse(reference);
    renderTodos(todos);
  }
}

getFromLocalStorage();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is simple,just add `addToLocalStorage` function to the event listener callback function will work.
`createTodoText` does run when todo list rendering,you want update localstorage,you need do that after todo item updated,which is after `blur`

```js
const createTodoText = (todo) => {
    const itemText = document.createElement('TEXTAREA');
    itemText.setAttribute('id', 'display-text');
    itemText.classList.add('todoText');
    itemText.addEventListener('input', function () {
        updateHeight(this);
    });
    itemText.value = todo.name;
    //update todo item when user clicks away
    itemText.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
        todo.name = e.currentTarget.value;
        addToLocalStorage(todos);
    });
    return itemText;
};
```

and I have update the [codepen](https://codepen.io/nay-kang/pen/RwVMjpL?editors=1011).
if you have further question,leave a comment

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot believe I missed that! How would I do the checkbox and delete as well?

Comment: I will also choose your answer when time limit lets me.

Comment: I had make the delete and checkbox work in the codepen

Comment: Whoops, I missed that. Thanks again @nay